# What's the easiest way to iterate on a file's lines, keeping a counter?

Tags: python

What's the cleanest code that iterates on the lines of a text file, while simultaniously increamenting a counter?

I understand that with multiple assignment, there's a cleaner syntax than

```
i = 0
for line in f:
    ...
    ++i
```

Comment: Note there is no `++` in Python.

Comment: @Sven: The nasty thing is that there is... two unary `+` which don't do anything, but it's syntactically valid.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
for i, line in enumerate(f):
  print i, line
```

As seen here: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: @Jacob Bowyer: It's only afternoon here -- ARE YOU FROM THE FUTURE? That would explain how your post was first: you were posting at 88 MPH!

Comment: Ah. 704 furlongs per hour then.

Comment: I still got nine rep from this so im not so upset but I woulda loved that tick :P

Answer (score 9):

```
for count, line in enumerate(f):
```

Enumerate starts at index 0 unless told otherwise providing a counter iterated at the same time as each item of your for loop

EDIT: As a side note you can change where enumerate starts from with the second argument e.g.
`for count, line in enumerate(f, 11)` would cause it to start at 11

Comment: +1 Word on the street is you outdrew me by 20 seconds. Is this true? :-p

Comment: @phooji: You may have been outdrawn, but your aim was more true -- you included a link to the documentation.

Comment: @S.Lott: Thanks, but I don't think that link took me more than 20 seconds to find ;)

Comment: Damn I lose out because of a documentation link?! D: *cries*